# Get resource usages with a simple command an a simple response in one line

Tags: ubuntu

Is there a way for Linux to get the following stats via the commandline with the result in a single string as response?

I wanna know the percentage of disk, memory and the CPU that's in use.

`$ command-to-get-CPU-percentage-usage`
result: `30%`. Just this string. No totals as you can get with `$ top`

Using Ubuntu 20 & 22 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
echo 'CPU percentage usage result': $(top -bn1 | grep 'Cpu(s)' | sed 's/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/')%"; Memory percentage usage result: $(free | awk '/Mem/{printf "%3.1f%%", $3/$2 * 100}'); Disk percentage usage result: $(df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "%s", $5}')"
```

You can then put it in your bashrc (such as ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile)

```
alias sysusage='echo 'CPU percentage usage result': $(top -bn1 | grep 'Cpu(s)' | sed 's/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/')%"; Memory percentage usage result: $(free | awk '/Mem/{printf "%3.1f%%", $3/$2 * 100}'); Disk percentage usage result: $(df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "%s", $5}')"'
```

Reload your shell

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now you can simply type `sysusage`

Comment: Great! That's awesome. Results looking good. Except for CPU, that's from 0 - 100 % in milliseconds, while the CPU isn't that in use.

Comment: I edited and tested on my VM and now reports the proper percentages